# shapeless tagged types runtime overhead

Tags: scala, types, shapeless

After reading across blogs, I get the impression that the tagged types provided by shapeless have no runtime overhead.

1. is it true that converting a raw type instance to tagged type has no runtime overhead?
2. is it true that converting a raw collection instance to tagged type collection has no runtime overhead?

With the related source code of tagged types from shapeless:

```
object tag {
  def apply[U] = new Tagger[U]
  trait Tagged[U]
  type @@[+T, U] = T with Tagged[U]
  class Tagger[U] {
    def apply[T](t : T) : T @@ U = t.asInstanceOf[T @@ U]
  }
}
```

For Question 1 with the example code:

```
trait IdTag
type Id = Long @@ IdTag

val id1: Id = tag[IdTag][Long](1000L) // way #1

val helper = tag[IdTag]
val id2: Id = helper[Long](1000L) // way #2

val id3: Id = 1000L.asInstanceOf[Id] // way #3
```

In way #1 and #2 `tag[IdTag]` creates an instance of `tag.Tagger[IdTag]`, which is a plain object. **Will the compiler eliminate the creation so as to have no runtime overhead? Or the cost of creation is so small that people simply neglect it?**

**Is way #3 legal and a better way to avoid intermediate object creation?**

For Question 2 with the example code:

```
val m0: Map[Long, Double] = Map(...) // a very large map

val m1: Map[Id, Double] = m0.map(e => tag[IdTag][Long](e._1) -> e._2) // way #1

val helper = tag[IdTag]
val m2: Map[Id, Double] = m0.map(e => helper[Long](e._1) -> e._2) // way #2

val m3: Map[Id, Double] = m0.asInstanceOf[Map[Id, Double]] // way #3
```

**Is it true that in view of performance, way #3 is the best, way #2 is worse as it needs to traverse the map and create a new map, way #3 is the worst as it needs not only traverse the map and create a new map, but also creates a log of `tag.Tagger`s?**